# Combine two varaibles in R

Tags: r

I have a varaible name a

```
a
-1
-1
-1
-1
 5
 6
 7
```

scenario 1

if a < 0 then b = 'asd

i used below code

```
i1 <- a <0

b[i1] <-"asd"


b
asd
asd
asd
na
na
na
```

Scenario 2 
if a >0 c

I used below code

```
i1 <-a >0 

c[i1] <-"sdx"

c
na
na
na
na
sdx
sdx
sdx
```

Now i want a varaibles d which will combine both b and c

```
d
asd
asd
asd 
sdx
sdx
sdx
```

Iam not able to do. I can only process either a<0 or a >0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it one go,

```
abcd <- data.frame(abc=c(-1, -1, -1, -1, 5, 6, 7))
abcd$dvar <- ifelse(abcd$abc<0, "asd", "sdx")
abcd
  abc dvar
1  -1 asd
2  -1 asd
3  -1 asd
4  -1 asd
5   5 sdx
6   6 sdx
7   7 sdx
```

Or this would be longer method

```
abcd$acond <- ifelse(abcd$abc<0, "asd", 0)
abcd$bcond <- ifelse(abcd$abc>0, "sdx", 0)
abcd$newvar <- c(abcd$acond[1:4], abcd$bcond[5:7])
```